# Some question about a sentence in the book Never Let Me go

Tags: grammar, meaning

I was stuck in Never Let Me Go by Kazuo Ishiguro.

> Because she said **she'd** a good mind to talk about it herself.

I understand the sentence but never read this form, does the **'d** mean **would**? Even so could you explain me this usecase?
Also how do you read it outloud ? I guess **she would a good mind** but it doesn't feel natural to me.

Thanks

Bonus:

> ... and explain why it was we went

Shouldn't be why we went or why we did go ?

Comment: Coincidence. I'm reading this book too, with other books at the same time. I find it's hard to love this book. tedious...

Comment: @Zhang a good book won't allow others to be read at the same time, and can even cost me a night's sleep.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're right, I read this one and stoped the others I've began almost automatically. Few night's sleep but glad it went this way

Comment: @WeatherVane, To me, reading English novel is a good cure for insomnia. When at the sleepless night, as long as I read some novels like Gone With the Wind, I would fall sleep within 10 minutes. :)

Comment: @WeatherVane, I do my reading almost all on my commute or traveling path, on the subway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It abbreviates the word **had**.

So the expanded sentence reads

> Because she said she had a good mind to talk about it herself.

---

The text in the bonus question is a bit wordy, but not incorrect, and your first version works well

> ... and explain why we went ...

But your second suggestion *"... and explain why we did go"* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks for both answers, I don't know why I forgot about **had** but here it is!
Also for the bonus, is it used orrally ?

Comment: Much more usually than written, unless quoted speech.

Answer (score 0):

"She'd" is a contraction of either "*she had*" or "*she would*".

In this case it is "she had":

> She had a good mind to talk about it herself.

They are both pronounced the same, and context determines which it is. Only "she had" makes sense in your example.

To a native English speaker, this is no more unusual than any other homonym.